# Want to make a consumer, not sure if kombu is enough or I need to also implement Celery

Tags: python, celery, kombu

I'm in the process of making a consumer for rabbtMQ. I'm using python and after research i decided to use Kombu. With Kombu I already connected to a queue in rabbit and read the messages. The code is

```
queue = Queue('someQueue')

def process(body, message):
    # Something
    message.ack()

# connections
with Connection(hostname="localhost", userid="****", password="****", port=****, virtualhost="/") as conn:

# consume
with conn.Consumer(queue, callbacks=[process]) as consumer:
    # Process messages and handle events on all channels
    while True:
        conn.drain_events()
```

It seems to work but I often see that Celery and Kombu are used together. I only need to consume the messages from the queue, is Kombu enough or should I integrate Celery as well. If so, does anyone has a good example, I found examples but they aren't clear to me. 
Also I want to make my queue durable=false but the consumer seems to have durable =true by default. How can I change this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if you want to create a queue and a consumer for it.No need of celery and kombu. Just RabbitMQ only.Use https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html (python client)

Comment: i see they use pika, can you maybe tell me the benefits of not using kombu?

Comment: The short answer is no, you don't need celery.  What are you looking for in an example?  You've already posted a simple example that you say works haven't you?  What is missing from the example you posted in your question?  Also, the durability of the queue is a server property.  As a client you cannot control whether the queue is durable or not.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a useful functionality i was missing.